# JMeter Test case to login over dynamic CRM

Tags: authentication, jmeter, dynamics-crm, access-token, load-testing

We have to migrate the existing visual studio web test over JMeter. Blazemeter we are using to record test case and when we are trying to run it over JMeter, it is failing while authentication against Dynamics CRM instance and it errors out 500 internal server error, with no other details.

Please let me know if you have done this already against any of the dynamic CRM instances.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think record-and-replay will work as the process is simply stupidly putting hard-coded values everywhere without making any [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)

The options are in:

1. Manually going through the recorded test plan identifying dynamic parameters, adding relevant [post-processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to extract dynamic values and replace hard-coded values with the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) from the post-processors
2. Re-record your test scenario using [Correlations Recorder Plugin for JMeter](https://github.com/Blazemeter/CorrelationRecorder), there you will be able to pre-populate the correlation rules beforehand
3. Re-record your test using [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80), it's capable of exporting recorded tests in "SmartJMX" mode with automatic detection and correlation of the dynamic parameters (most probably you will still have to do some manual polishing)

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved, need to authenticate against AAD OAuth2 with client credentials flow before calling any Dynamic CRM API.

I am providing all required details to get authenticated first and then parsing response to retrieve access token and passing in subsequent API calls and that works. This is what have done. Please let me know if anyone wanted to know details about this.